# Missing on_site in Stack Apps site data in associated_users from stackauth query

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth

This is what I get for Stack Apps:

```
    {
        "display_name": "user",
        "email_hash": "11aa11...22bb22...",
        "reputation": 101,
        "user_id": 0000,
        "user_type": "registered"
    }
```

And this is what I get from other sites:

```
    {
        "display_name": "user",
        "email_hash": "11aa11...22bb22...",
        "on_site": {
            "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com",
            "description": "Q&A about Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User",
            "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/mso/apple-touch-icon.png",
            "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/mso/img/logo.png",
            "name": "Stack Overflow Meta",
            "site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com"
        },
        "reputation": 101,
        "user_id": 0000,
        "user_type": "registered"
    }
```

As you can see, the whole `on_site` portion is missing.

Comment: I can reproduce this as well for me.  Should I code a workaround?  Or will this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that StackAuth does not show stackapps either.

A failure of the cascading type.

Sounds like an example where a persistent cache would be helpfule.